# Knockout observable shared between browsers - Subscribe only when value changed locally

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to have some observables shared between all users connected to the webpage.

When an observable is modified, the updated value is sent to the backend (with socket.io in my case or any other method).

When the backend receive the updated value, it is sending the value to all the users. Even the user which sent the new value. I cannot change this behaviour of the backend.

To verify if an observable has changed I used the `subscribe` method of the observable.

How is it possible to know in the subscribe method if the observable has been modified locally or remotely so I can send the value to the backend only when the value has been modified locally ?

Some code below:

my observable:

```
self.param1 = ko.observable(0);
```

is subscribed to send update to backend

```
self.param1.subscribe(function() {
    // send value to backend
    // this function should not start if param1 is modified remotely
    // to avoid loops 
});
```

When a new value is received from backend the observable is modified remotely

```
self.param1(new_value_received_from_backend);
```

[Here is a JSFiddle simulating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/leszekhanusz/NYhd2/)

Try to change a parameter twice very fast and you notice a loop is created and the parameter change between two values every two seconds.

Comment: Observables don't trigger their subscribers if their value does not change. So if the anyone (server or client) updates the value, the subscribers will be triggered *once*. If the same value is received again, the subscribers won't be triggered. There should not be a loop.

Comment: A loop can still happen if there is lag between the server and the client. Try it yourself and change one parameter in the JSFiddle twice in less than two seconds.

Comment: Hmm, just a though, but if the View(Model)s should respond differently based on whether the change was done locally or remotely (or more abstract: based on which client changed it), you may need to *model* that in your DTO and ViewModel.

Comment: I tried to separate local and remote observables [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leszekhanusz/NYhd2/1/). I think no loop can happen now because the local observable is set as the remote only when the user is clicking on the parameter. But it is still sending the remote value to the backend when clicking on it. It comes back to the question on how to stop a subscribe to fire on some condition.

Comment: Of course, in this case it is possible to verify that the local value is different than the remote value in the subscribe function... Creating an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Jeroen advice I splitted the observable into two:

```
self.param1_local
```

and

```
self.param1_remote
```

The value of the parameter is sent to the backend only if `self.param1_local` was modified AND it is different than `self.param1_remote`

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/leszekhanusz/NYhd2/2/)